# Python XML BeautifulSoup get text of children nodes

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

With a previous project I scraped data out of XML tag attributes, but I cannot figure out how to get the text of children XML nodes. The program pulls id's from a text file and plugs them into a url, which is then parsed. The XML is as follows:

```
<Article>
    <Sometag Owner="Steve" Status="online">
        <ID Version="1">231119634</PMID>
        <DateCreated>
            <Year>2012</Year>
            <Month>10</Month>
            <Day>10</Day>
        </DateCreated>
```

I want to get the `year` `month` and `day` text out of the children tags of `DateCreated`

So far I have the following, with no luck

```
    link = "http://somelink.com/"+line.rstrip('\n')+"?id=xml&format=text"
    args = (curlLink + ' -L ' + link + ' -o c:\\temp.txt --proxy-ntlm -x http://myproxy:80 -k -U:') 
    sp = subprocess.Popen(args) #run curl
    sp.wait() #Wait for it to finish before proceeding
    xml_string = open(r'C:\temp.txt', 'r').read() #read in the temporary file
    os.remove(r'C:\temp.txt') # clean up
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string)
    result = soup.find('DateCreated')
    if result is not None:
        date = result.children.get_text()
        g.write(date +"\n")
```

Comment: sick thanks for the downvote for no reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different ways to get the information from data:

```
year = int(date.Year.text)
month = int(date.Month.text)
day = int(date.Day.text)
```

or `date.text` gives you the text content as a string. What you should use depends on what you really need.